# jQuery addClass doens't work

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have a menu in which different buttons are placed. When the initial page is loaded, one button is active (declared via `class="active`). Now, when I click on a different button, the class will be removed and added to the just clicked button. The code worked well, then I tried something different in jquery but I removed it, but my code isn't working, even though I have a different project in which I have the same code and it's working.

Here's my Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3e2MW/1/

Comment: `$(this).click(` here `this` is the document....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$(this)` to bind the click event handler which is wrong.Use this:

```
$('#nav ul li a').click(function() {
           $("#nav ul li a").removeClass("active");
           $(this).addClass('active');
           return false;});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3e2MW/2/)**

Comment: Thank you!! Didn't see that!

Comment: is it possible to select a certain button when it is a certain day? like when it is monday, button monday needs to be active.?

Comment: Yes you can. Find the day using `var d = new Date();var n = d.getDay();`. Then use switch condition and  addClass active to respective button based on day value.

Comment: ok, and how is this gonna work? I am actually new to jquery. Could you give me an jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#nav ul li a").click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $("#nav ul li a").removeClass("active");
           $(this).addClass('active');  
           return false;
         });
 });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3e2MW/7/)

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is you already posted then why `return false;`.

Comment: is it possible to select a certain button when it is a certain day? like when it is monday, button monday needs to be active.?

Comment: yes you can add class names to button like monday,tuesday etc. Then according to the day you can use like $(".monday").addClass("active");

Comment: ok, and how is this gonna work? I am actually new to jquery. Could you give me an jsfiddle?

Comment: oh yeah! You made my day!! And now one last question. is it possible to load an initial page like that button? THis is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JF8Tw/ and I want to load page monday, when it's monday. Is that possible ?